# Constraining a Double Pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

My question is, how do I apply boundary constraints to a Lagrangian such as:

$90 > \theta_1 > -45$

and

$\theta_2 > 0$

I am trying to use a constrained double pendulum to simulate an underhand throw. I am trying to use the Lagrangian defined from [Wolfram's site](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html) equation (9) and add constraints to it through Lagrange multipliers.

My confusion comes from the fact that constraints for Lagrange multipliers are normally written as equalities with multiple variables such as:

$ f(\theta_1, \theta_2) = \theta_1 + 2\theta_2 = 90$

and not as inequalities.

When I looked up inequality optimization, the method I got was to set the inequality as an equality and then solve for the boundaries. This doesn't make to me (in my application) because the system might not be at the boundary through the entire simulation, so setting $\theta_2 = 0$ doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This is not an answer but a hint. Try searching for "non holonomic constraints" in double pendulums. You might find the answer that way.

Comment: Constraint reduces the degrees of freedom, but your constraint is numerical, you can’t solve it with Lagrange method.

Comment: Do you have a recommended method instead?

Comment: If you solve the equation numerical you can use limiter integrator for a state variable like $\Theta(t)$ for example

Comment: Why not a variable change like $\theta_1 = f(\mu)$ with $-\frac{\pi}{4}\le f(\mu)\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ like a logistic function?

Comment: Your simulation will work better if you use a system of motorized hinges and ignore gravity. A double pendulum won't approximate a throw, which is muscle-powered at every hinge and hinged at least four times - shoulder, elbow, wrist, knuckles - and probably more.